# How to use Azure Data Factory for importing data incrementally from MySQL to Azure Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory to periodically import data from MySQL to Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

The data goes through a staging blob storage on an Azure storage account, but when I run the pipeline it fails because it can't separate the blob text back to columns. Each row that the pipeline tries to insert into the destination becomes a long string which contains all the column values delimited by a "⯑" character.

I used Data Factory before, without trying the incremental mechanism, and it worked fine. I don't see a reason it would cause such a behavior, but I'm probably missing something.

I'm attaching the JSON that describes the pipeline with some minor naming changes, please let me know if you see anything that can explain this.

Thanks!

EDIT: Adding exception message:

> Failed execution Database operation failed. Error message from
>   database execution :
>   ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Com‌​mon.Shared.HybridDel‌​iveryException,Messa‌​ge=Error
>   happened when loading data into SQL Data
>   Warehouse.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Typ‌​e=System.Data.SqlCli‌​ent.SqlException,Mes‌​sage=Query
>   aborted-- the maximum reject threshold (0 rows) was reached while
>   reading from an external source: 1 rows rejected out of total 1 rows
>   processed.
>   (/f4ae80d1-4560-4af9-9e74-05de941725ac/Data.8665812f-fba1-40‌​7a-9e04-2ee5f3ca5a7e‌​.txt)
>              Column ordinal: 27, Expected data type: VARCHAR(45) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value:* ROW OF VALUES
>   * (Tokenization failed), Error: Not enough columns in this
>   line.,},],'.

```
{
"name": "CopyPipeline-move_incremental_test",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "RelationalSource",
                    "query": "$$Text.Format('select * from [table] where InsertTime >= \\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\\' AND InsertTime < \\'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\\'', WindowStart, WindowEnd)"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "SqlDWSink",
                    "sqlWriterCleanupScript": "$$Text.Format('delete [schema].[table] where [InsertTime] >= \\'{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\\' AND [InsertTime] <\\'{1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}\\'', WindowStart, WindowEnd)",
                    "allowPolyBase": true,
                    "polyBaseSettings": {
                        "rejectType": "Value",
                        "rejectValue": 0,
                        "useTypeDefault": true
                    },
                    "writeBatchSize": 0,
                    "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                },
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "columnMappings": "column1:column1,column2:column2,column3:column3"
                },
                "enableStaging": true,
                "stagingSettings": {
                    "linkedServiceName": "StagingStorage-somename",
                    "path": "somepath"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "InputDataset-input"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OutputDataset-output"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                "concurrency": 10,
                "style": "StartOfInterval",
                "retry": 3,
                "longRetry": 0,
                "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Hour",
                "interval": 1
            },
            "name": "Activity-0-_Custom query_->[schema]_[table]"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2017-06-01T05:29:12.567Z",
    "end": "2099-12-30T22:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "datafactory_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

}

Comment: Could you supply more steps and exception?

Comment: Failed execution

Database operation failed. Error message from database execution : ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error happened when loading data into SQL Data Warehouse.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Query aborted-- the maximum reject threshold (0 rows) was reached while reading from an external source: 1 rows rejected out of total 1 rows processed. (/f4ae80d1-4560-4af9-9e74-05de941725ac/Data.8665812f-fba1-407a-9e04-2ee5f3ca5a7e.txt)

Comment: Column ordinal: 27, Expected data type: VARCHAR(45) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Offending value:* TOO MANY CHARACTERS FOR RESPONSE* (Tokenization failed), Error: Not enough columns in this line.,},],'.

Comment: About the steps I took: I was going through the pipeline creation wizard, creating a scheduled pipeline with a MySQL source and Azure Data Warehouse destination through a staging blob storage within Azure. The resulting pipeline is described in the JSON above.

Comment: Please add the detail info to questions that will help communities to understand. As Paul Andrew said it seems  data is poorly formed. Please have a try to use custom activities.

Comment: Sure thing. Added the exception message to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what your doing is right, but the data is poorly formed (common problem, none UTF-8 encoding) so ADF can't parse the structure as you require. When I encounter this I often have to add a custom activity to the pipeline that cleans and prepares the data so it can then be used in a structured way by downstream activities. Unfortunately this is a big be overhead in the development of the solution and will require you to write a C# class to deal with the data transformation.

Also remember ADF has none of its own compute, it only invokes other services, so you'll also need an Azure Batch Service to execute to compiled code.

Sadly there is no magic fix here. Azure is great to Extract and Load your perfectly structured data, but in the real world we need other services to do the Transform or Cleaning meaning we need a pipeline that can ETL or I prefer ECTL.

Here's a link on create ADF custom activities to get you started: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/11/creating-azure-data-factory-custom-activities/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggeling with the same message, sort of, when importing from Azure sql db to Azure DWH using Data Factory v.2 using staging (which implies Polybase). I've learned that Polybase will fail with error messages related to  incorrect data types etc. The message I've received is much similar to the one mentioned [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2016/06/21/polybase-setup-errors-and-possible-solutions/), even though I'm not using Polybase directly from SQL, but via Data Factory.

Anyways, the solution for me was to avoid NULL values for columns of decimal or numeric type, e.g. ISNULL(mynumericCol, 0) as mynumericCol.